# Would a t-test apply? Statistical Test Suggestion

Tags: hypothesis-testing

Given two lists of characters. For example

List #1

A
C
O
P

List #2

A
O
R
T

How would you test whether the two lists differ significantly or not. I feel like a t-test can be applied, but I'm not sure how given I have character values as opposed to numerical values (i.e. I cant compute means).

**Question: Is there a way to show that the two lists of characters are generated from the same population given their similarities**

Thanks for any help

Comment: What is the data-generating process? What do the letters represent?

Comment: It's actually a simplified example meant to represent a gene list. In cells there are genes that are differentially expressed in tumor vs normal cells. And I have two lists of genes from different data sets and I want to be able to say statistically that these two list of genes do not differ significantly from one another

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer makes little sense. You're **NOT** comparing directly the ammio acid or nucleotides. You're trying to conduct a differential expression test of two experiments. The dependent variable is the abundance of each RNA sample and the values are integers.

Comparing directly the ammio acid or nucleotides is more like pairwise alignment, but this has nothing to do what you're trying to do.

Let's get back to the test. You **could** use a t-test to test for the differences, but it's not recommended. Not that it's invalid, the sample sizes in a medical research is small, so a simple t-test gives little power.

We typically use other statistical tests. I don't know which one is the best because this depends on your data and assumptions. I have been using the edgeR bioconductor package which models a negative-binomial GLM. I've also seen other bioinformatic packages using F-test.

Read http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/edgeR/inst/doc/edgeRUsersGuide.pdf for more details. Pay close attention to "2.7 Negative binomial models" section.

Read http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC154570/pdf/gb-2003-4-4-210.pdf on why a t-test isn't recommended.